# Stitched images not well aligned at all points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I'm trying to stitch multiple images together, and the result I get has images stitched, but they are only aligned at some points. I believe this is due to the translation of images. Here's one of the results

[image]

The images is not well aligned in 10 o clock to 12 o clock region.

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: to globally stitch correctly you have to know both perfectly: camera and scene geometry. You probably  dont know your geometry, so there is one more chance left if you use perspective homographies. If you have undistorted the lens. A perspective homography is perfectly suited for 2 cases: 1. if both stitched images belong to a common plane (like a house's wall); 2. any scenr if the camera center is fixed.

Comment: Another idea is to force the computation of the homography from features distributed within the whole image to distribute the inevitable errors within the whole image. Behrens et al has written at least one paper on that topic.

Comment: How is perspective homography different from the findhomography api that I'm using? Or are they the same thing?

Comment: findHomography computes a perspective homography. But probably your scene isnt a plane and your camera doesn't purely rotate around the xamera center (abd/or you didnt undistort the lens). That's why you only get good results at a part of the image and errors everywhere else.

Comment: The feature distribution paper is "Analysis of Feature Point Distributions for Fast Image Mosaicking Algorithms"

Comment: Hi, @Micka, I still haven't been unable to solve it. Could you perhaps give an example if that's not too much? Here's how I currently find homography: `H, status = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)`. I didn't quite understand your second comment, I've spent a while just reading it over and over again.

Comment: findHomography chooses the best subset of all matches. If the image does not hold the homography constraints (completely plain scene or purely rotating camera) this means that probably only a small subset of your features is selected, which best fit to the constraint. You will have to write your own homography computation algorithm and in the end, you can't compute a homography that will give you a perfect stitching there, because of those constraints which your setting doesn't fulfill. All that can be achieved is to distribute the error all around the image.

Comment: @Micka, it turns out that if I stitch the images in a different order, this issue gets solved. My code requires an image to start with (a base image). If I change the base image to another, this issue gets resolved because the part causing the error gets overlaid by another image, which is perfectly aligned. Any idea about how I can determine the best base image automatically?